# Geth Dump Has Been Running For A Week

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, ethminer, state-trie

For my project I want to dump the full state data of all Eth wallets/balances. I have a fully synced Geth node with all state data (over 2TB).

I started a block dump

```
geth dump 7300000 --datadir "/Volumes/Ethereum/"
```

It has been running for over a week and still isn't done. My system manager says that geth has read over 8.5TB so far. Why does it need to do this much work to export the state data? Why does it take this long? I've tested this before on earlier blocks and it worked.

Edit: Using a 4TB external SSD, 2TB RAID0, using USB-c connector.